# java check for particular value for a field

Tags: java

I have requirement to check for a particular field only particular values are allowed, how to do that best in java.

For example:

For a "Status" field  only allowed values are "eq" and "in"
For a "Date" field only allowed values are "gt","ge" and "eq"

My method will look something like this,

```
boolean checkFieldAndOperatorMatching(String field, String operator);
```

for example, if some one passes

```
 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("status", "eq"); //correct
 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("status", "in"); //correct

 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("status", "gt"); // not correct

 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("date", "gt"); //correct
 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("date", "ge"); //correct
 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("date", "eq"); //correct

 checkFieldAndOperatorMatching("date", "in"); // not correct
```

Comment: You could try using a `Map`.

Comment: Create Map and set values for both, field and operator.

Comment: i want know is there any way that i declare field and operators in the properties file and read based on the field which operators are allowed.

Comment: how can you use the map, as it accepts only one key. duplicates are overwritten.

Comment: You can use `enum` for allowed values  `enum Date { GT, GE, EQ}`

Comment: I have many fields, if i declare enum for each field i will end up many enums.

Comment: then you are thinking in right direction, us a property file, `date=gt,ge,eq` fetch the string for `key(first argument)` and check if the provided `value(second argument)` is present in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Using Properties, you can do similar(change to suit your requirements) to below:

```
    public boolean checkFieldAndOperatorMatching(String field, String operator) {

    // can be loaded once
    // make it static or use a factory method
    // which returns same Properties instance every time if already loaded
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("D:\\fields.properties");) {

        properties.load(fin);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String validValues = properties.getProperty(field);

    return Arrays.asList(validValues.split(",")).contains(operator);
}
```

where, `fields.properties` contains:

```
date=gt,ge,eq
status=eq,in
```

Comment: Not the best solution, seeing as this would accept any permutation of the characters in the field. So even `gt,ge` would be accepted. And you also load the file each check.

Comment: @Obicer, You can change it to `load the properties only once`, you can `split the value string` to get valid values and validate `operator` against each element. Up to you to change it to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Enums` for `Date` and `Status` , which contains the permitted values:-

```
enum Status {
    eq,in
}
enum Date {
    gt,ge,eq
}
```

And then iterate through enum to check if the values passed in parameter exist in enums:-

```
static boolean checkFieldAndOperatorMatching(String field, String operator){

    if(field.equals("Status")){ //if field is Status

        for (Status s : Status.values()) {

             if(operator.equals(s.toString())){

                 return true;
             }

             }
             return false;
        }

     if(field.equals("Date")){ //if field is Date

         for (Date d : Date.values()) {
             if(operator.equals(d.toString())){

                 return true;
             }

         }
             return false;
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have many fields for validation, you can do the following

- Use DB to store the key-values and caches those in Collections to validate (IF you have grow-able number of fields)
- Use Properties file to represent $field = $values ( comma separated) and read them in your validate method (If you have mostly static list of fields with constant values
- Use enums if its completely static values. I agree that it will make you write extra lines of code, but is one of the good practice to have constant field values in enums.